MemoryError inside celery, but no error outside
I'm using Django 5.1.3 and Celery 5.4.0.
I have one task.
If I run it without Celery, then everything is OK. If I run it with the help of Celery, I get MemoryError.
What is the reason for this?
Can I tune somehow Celery to avoid this error?
It would be good if the behavior was consistent.
Thank you.

Run top or htop to see how much RAM is left when you run the task.
